# attempting to replace open() with a pandas subset, but I am given an __exit__ error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, contextmanager

I am trying to work with pylabels to create nametags for an upcoming event.  In one section of the code, there is this tid-bit:

```
with open(os.path.join(base_path, "names.txt")) as names:
    sheet.add_labels(name.strip() for name in names)
```

where `sheet = labels.Sheet(specs, write_name, border=True)`.  So essentially, this will load each line of "names.txt" and call the function 'write_name', using specifications in 'specs', and add each name to unique labels.  I'm attempting to change this code to the following:

```
with text_file[["Name"]] as names:
    sheet.add_labels(name.strip() for name in names)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sticker.V.7.py", line 173, in <module>
    with text_file[["Name"]] as names:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Can anyone help me understand what **exit** means in this context?  I do not understand from other submissions.

I am hoping to add this subsetting aspect so that I can add further details to the nametags.

I am using Python3.5

Comment: What is `text_file` and why `[["Name"]]`, obviously it is not something exitable and thus cannot be used with `with`.

Comment: text_file is a dataframe made through pd.read_csv.  [['Name']] is a column of the text_file dataframe.  as text_file isn't a function, it should be exitable

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone help me understand what `__exit__` means in this context? I do not understand from other submissions.  ... As `text_file` isn't a function, it should be exitable.

When you use [`with` statement context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers), that object must define these two methods:

- `__enter__`
- `__exit__`

Whatever `text_file[["Name"]]` is (a Pandas DataFrame, it seems), it doesn't implement either of these methods.  As indicated by the traceback, it doesn't define `__enter__` at all, so execution stops right there and raises an exception.

I don't see a need to use a DataFrame as a context manager.  A typical use-case is when you want to ensure that something happens at the end of the `with` block, namely, closing a file stream.  (Like a `try`/`finally` block--you want to make sure `__exit__` gets called unconditionally.)  With a Pandas DataFrame, I'm not sure if there is any analogy that would necessitate have those two dunder methods.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! ill try another method that includes an exit call.