# Applying a for loop on each row of a specifc file column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am attempting to create a bit of code that will apply a function on each row of a specific database column.  Other posts I have seen appear to apply a function over the row of all columns, which is not what I need.

What I have attempted to do is to subset the data to get a database with only the column I need ('blargh' in script below), and then try to churn the database through a for loop.  However, I'm not sure how to iterate over each row.  Could someone help me by understanding how to make the for loop below function?

```
import pandas as pd
import os.path

# Get the path to the demos directory.
base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

text_file = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(base_path, "names.txt"), sep = ';    ' , engine='python')

# subsetting
blargh = text_file[["Name"]]
print(blargh)

# attempting to make a for loop
for row in blargh:
    print(row)
```

Edit:  As requested, here is the background for why I am attempting this.  [This is an attempt to fix a problem I was investigating in an earlier post but I haven't made any worthwhile progress.  Click here to see the original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312256/attempting-to-replace-open-with-a-pandas-subset-but-i-am-given-an-exit-er)

Essentially, I am attempting to use the package pylabels to create printable name tags.  The original code uses a txt file where every row is a name.  I wish to add more details to the nametags, so I am attempting to modify the code to take in a database and add the appropriate information to each label.  The original script had this code:

```
with open(os.path.join(base_path, "names.txt")) as names:
    sheet.add_labels(name.strip() for name in names)
```

where `sheet = labels.Sheet(specs, write_name, border=True)`.  When I attempted to modify this to:

```
with text_file[["Name"]] as names:
    sheet.add_labels(name.strip() for name in names)
```

I got a `AttributeError: __exit__`.  Someone suggested using try/finally statement, but I can't seem to get it to work.

(full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sticker.V.7.py", line 173, in <module>
    with text_file[["Name"]] as names:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

)

Comment: Could you provide some input data and the expected output?

Comment: If you are using a for loop over a column, you're usually doing something wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display/Print one column from a DataFrame of Series in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122910/display-print-one-column-from-a-dataframe-of-series-in-pandas)

Comment: I was attempting to use a with statement earlier, but was given a failed __exit__ statement.  I was told by stack members that I should try something else.  I will edit and add more details about the purpose.

Comment: Are you trying to `apply` *a function* to the column data? Or just print it out? If print, see the flagged duplicate

Comment: What is the full AttributeError?

Comment: when I was using the with statement, the full error was
'Traceback (most recent call last):'
'  File "sticker.V.7.py", line 173, in <module>'
'    with text_file[["Name"]] as names:'
'AttributeError: __exit__'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save a made dataframe (i.e. text_file[["Name"]]) to the file. So:

```
data = text_file[["Name"]]
data.to_csv("data.csv", sep=",")
```

The with statement works only with special objects that have **enter** and **exit** functions defined. DataFrame is not that object, but the result of open("file.csv", "r") has this ability.

So now you are able to:

```
with open(os.path.join(base_path, "data.csv")) as names:
    sheet.add_labels(name.strip() for name in names)
```

Comment: This has solved the `__exit__` problem, but now the system is adding a number in front of the name.  ex, if there is the name Darth Vader, it's creating a pdf with 1,Darth Vader .  I added `index=False, header=False` to the data.to_csv arguments to fix that.  thanks!

Comment: If it is the answer to your question, please mark my answer ;)